# When trying to run PnP SPFx Yeoman generator I get this error message: 'The "data" argument must be of type string ...'

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, yeoman-generator

Here is the full message:
!!! Project needs to be upgraded !!!
Error @pnp/spfx

The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received null

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command to skip the version check:

```
yo @pnp/spfx --skip-version-check
```